# Why are paranthesis added to print statement by default in Dataframe shape?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm doing a MOOC question in which I'm supposed to import a .tsv file as a DataFrame and print certain output. As shown below :
Shape: r,c
Columns:
col1
col2
...

My code prints the row and columns as integer values separately, but when I print them together, parenthesis are added to beginning and end. Instead of printing it as Shape: r, c it is printing it as Shape: (r,c). Is there something that I'm unaware about happening in the background?

```
import pandas as pd

def main():
    file_as_dataframe = pd.read_csv("C:\\moocfi.test-my-code\\tmcdata\\TMC workspace\\Exercises\\hy\\hy-data-analysis-with-python-2020\\part04-e03_municipal_information\\src\\municipal.tsv", sep='\t')
    rows = file_as_dataframe.shape[0]
    columns = file_as_dataframe.shape[1]
    print(rows) #Prints 490
    print(columns)  #prints 7
    print(f'Shape: {rows, columns}')    #Prints Shape: (490, 7)
    print('Columns:')
    for each_column in file_as_dataframe.columns:
        print(each_column)
    return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: `{rows, columns}` is a tuple inside an f-string expression.

Comment: @khelwood so any two comma separated values in a fstring are assumed to be tuple by default?

Comment: A literal comprising values separated by commas indicates a tuple, whether or not it is inside an f-string expression. If you write `x=1,2`, that is a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

Since what was pointed by @khelwood. You can try to replace the print line by:

```
print(f'Shape: {rows}, {columns}')
```